# How to update the widget form when the image is selected?

Tags: widgets

I have created a custom widget. There are 2 things that I can't do:

1. I need to open the new media uploader window when the button "Select The Image" is clicked.
2. When the image is selected from the media uploader I need to show the image in widget form. Only when I click on "Save" button, the image appears.

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Basic Image Widget
   */

   class pippin_simple_authors_widget extends WP_Widget {

       /** constructor */
       function pippin_simple_authors_widget() {
           parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'Basic Image Widget');
       }

       /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
       function widget($args, $instance) {
           extract( $args );

           $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
           $description = $instance['description'];    

           if(!$size)
               $size = 40;
           ?>

           <li>
               <div class="cat-img-wrap">
                   <img src="<?php echo esc_url($instance['image_uri']); ?>" />
               </div>
               <div class="cat-text-wrap">
                   <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                   <?php                        
                   echo $description; 
                   ?>
               </div>
           </li>        

           <?php
       }

       /** @see WP_Widget::update */
       function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
           $instance = $old_instance;
           $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
           $instance['description'] = strip_tags($new_instance['description']);    
           $instance['image_uri'] = strip_tags($new_instance['image_uri']);        
           return $instance;
       }

       /** @see WP_Widget::form */
       function form($instance) {  

           $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
           $description =  esc_attr($instance['description']);     

           ?>
            <p>
             <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
             <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
           </p>

            <p>
             <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('description'); ?>"><?php _e('Description:'); ?></label>
             <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('description'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('description'); ?>"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>     
           </p>
           <p>
           <?php if($instance['image_uri']): ?>
           <img src="<?php echo esc_url($instance['image_uri']); ?>" />
           <?php endif; ?>      
         <input type="text" class="img" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_uri'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image_uri']; ?>" style="display:none;" />
         <input type="button" class="select-img" value="Select The Image" />
       </p>


           <?php
       }

   } // class utopian_recent_posts
   add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("pippin_simple_authors_widget");'));


   function hrw_enqueue()
   {
     wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
     wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
     wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
     // moved the js to an external file, you may want to change the path
     wp_enqueue_script('hrw', '/wp-content/plugins/basic-image-widget/script.js', null, null, true);
   }
   add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'hrw_enqueue');
   ```

#### script.js

```
var image_field;
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('click', 'input.select-img', function(evt){
    image_field = $(this).siblings('.img');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
  });
  window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    imgurl = $('img', html).attr('src');
    image_field.val(imgurl);
    tb_remove();
  }
});
```